# User Defined R function for comparing vectors

Tags: r, function, if-statement

So I am trying to write an R function called `both_na(x,y)`, that takes two vectors (`x` and `y`) of the same length and returns the number of indices that have an `NA` in both vectors `x` and `y`. If the `x` and `y` are of different lengths, the function should print out “vectors are not of equal length” and return 0.

I am not being able to do the last part where vectors are not of equal length are to be printed.

```
both_na <- function(x, y) {
  sum(is.na(x) & is.na(y))
}
```

What type of if and else statement should I be using?

Answer (score 2):

You could generalize this to an arbitrary number of vectors. The entered vectors are `list`ed which facilitates to compare their `lengths`. Only if the `var`iance is zero, we may `cbind` and count `NA`s in rows, otherwise we return `0`.

```
f <- \(...) {
  lst <- list(...)
  ln <- length(lst)
  stopifnot(ln > 1L)
  ls <- lengths(lst)
  if (sum(ls) == 0L) {  ## all lengths null
    0L
  }
  else if (var(ls) != 0) {  ## different lengths
    warning("vectors are not of equal length")
    0L
  } else { 
    sum(rowSums(is.na(do.call(cbind, lst))) == ln)
  }
}
```

### Usage

```
f(x, y)
# [1] 2
f(x, y[1:3])
# [1] 0
# Warning message:
#  In f(x, y[1:3]) : vectors are not of equal length
f(x, y, z)
# [1] 7
f(x, y[1:3], z)
# [1] 0
# Warning message:
# In f(x, y[1:3], z) : vectors are not of equal length
f(x, y, NULL)
# [1] 0
# Warning message:
# In f(x, y, NULL) : vectors are not of equal length
f(NULL, NULL)
# [1] 0
f(x)
f()
f(NULL)
# Error in f(NULL) : length(lst) > 1L is not TRUE
```

---

*Data:*

```
x <- c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 
1L, NA)

y <- c(NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA)

z <- c(1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
1L, NA)
```

Answer (score 1):

This function does what you nedd.

```r
both_na <- function(x, y){
  if(length(x) != length(y)) {
    print('Vectors are not of equal length')
    return(0)
  }
  
  sum(is.na(x) & is.na(y))
}

x <- c(1, NA, 2, 3, NA, 5)
y <- c(1, NA, NA, 3, NA, 5)
z <- c(1, NA, NA, 3, NA)

both_na(x, y)
#> [1] 2
both_na(x, z)
#> [1] "Vectors are not of equal length"
#> [1] 0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: OP’s code returns the count of indices where both vectors are NA. Yours returns locations.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I fixed it